# generalize lapply/map for all permutations of multiple arguments

Tags: r, nested-loops, lapply, mapply

I want to test whether a function f, that has multiple arguments works as desired.

```
f <- function(x1, ..., xm) {...}
```

What I want to do is to specify lists

```
x1_arguments <- list(x1_1, ..., x1_n1)
...
xm_arguments <- list(xm_1, ..., xm_nm)
```

and check that f works for all possible combinations of x1, ..., xm.

I could of course

1. Write e.g. a dataframe such  that the rows contain the possible combinations of x1, ... xm arguments. and then loop over the rows
2. Write a nested for / lapply loop

I would like to make it prettier however as 1. creates a possibly large object that is absolutely unnecessary and 2. looks ugly

Is there an inbuilt R-function that allows you to do that, e.g. a generalized lapply function that loops over multiple lists?

Comment: n = 2 was just for illustration, should have made that clearer

Comment: You're looking for mapply()

Answer (score 1):

There is an inbuilt function for applying over multiple iterables:

```
mapply()
```

In your case:

```
mapply(f, x = x_arguments, y = y_arguments)
```

You might need to arrange `x` and `y` so that all possible instances combinations match up, but once you do you can use this function.

Comment: actually that is not what I want. I want it to evaluate ALL possible combinations, e.g. if x_arguments = (1,2), y_arguments = (3,4) I want it to evaluate (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2.4)

Comment: @Sebastian then you just need to fix your inputs, `xi <- rep(seq_along(x), length(y)); yi <- rep(seq_along(y), each = length(x))` give the indices of `x` and `y`, then `mapply(f, x = x_arguments[xi], y = y_arguments[yi])`

Comment: this would be basically my solution 1. and I want to avoid creating unneccessary data

Comment: change your function to be `f <- function(x1i, x2i, ..., xmi) {x1 <- x1_args[x1i]; x2 <- x2_args[x2i]; ...}`, ie, the only place you use your argument list is in `f` and are only passing the indices to `x1_arguments`... this is basically a generalized, nested for-loop for `mapply`; your call would look like this `mapply(f, xi, yi)`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `outer`.

```
outer(1:3, 4:6, FUN=`^`)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]   16   32   64
# [3,]   81  243  729
```

To obtain vector format, use

```
as.vector(outer(1:3, 4:6, FUN=`^`))
# [1]   1  16  81   1  32 243   1  64 729
```

`mapply` basically throws just the diagonal.

```
mapply(FUN=`^`, 1:3, 4:6)
# [1]   1  32 729
```

### Edit

For more arguments you could try `expand.grid`.

```
f <- function(x, y, z) x + y - z
```

Just expand your arguments to all possible <strike>combinations</strike> permutations.

```
args <- expand.grid(
  x1=1:3,
  x2=4:6,
  xn=7:9)

head(args)
#   x1 x2 xn
# 1  1  4  7
# 2  2  4  7
# 3  3  4  7
# 4  1  5  7
# 5  2  5  7
# 6  3  5  7
```

And unpack them into `.GlobalEnv`.

```
list2env(args, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Then you can use `mapply`.

```
mapply(f, x1, x2, xn)
# [1] -2 -1  0 -1  0  1  0  1  2 -3 -2 -1 -2 -1  0 -1  0  1 -4 -3
# [21] -2 -3 -2 -1 -2 -1  0
```

Comment: @Sebastian what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I want to have more than only x and y (the example in the question was only for illustrative purposes and a changed it now)

Comment: @Sebastian See edit to my answer and tell me what you think?

Comment: I thinks it is an okish solution (+ 1) (my own solution would have been to use expand.grid and then loop over the rows), however the object created by extend.grid is somewhat unnecessary and ideally I would like to avoid it...

Comment: @Sebastian Hope you don't mind I've reworded the title of your question to give it more meaning and attract possible better answers.